# aws-amplify ERR: "Cannot read property 'DeploymentBucketName' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify

I have a local React project and initialized @aws-amplify/cli (v. 6.14.13) in the root folder.
Command `amplify push` runs into "**Cannot read property 'DeploymentBucketName' of undefined**".
I tried `amplify pull`, and i get "Environment 'prototype' not found.", even though the enviroment was deployed yesterday.
Furthermore i tried `amplify env pull --restore` and even `amplify delete` all running into some form of "**Cannot read property 'DeploymentBucketName' of undefined**".

Comment: Were you able to solve it. And how?

Comment: no, sadly i had to set it up again.